# Using mod_rewrite to resource outside of DocumentRoot

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have what I thought to be a very simple and classic use-case of `mod_rewrite` that is stumping me.

I have a file structure like this:

```
/var/www/site 
/var/www/site/webapp    <-- js application     
/var/www/site/index.php <-- php entry point
/var/www/site/.. other folders..
```

I want my users to navigate to "mysite.com" which will load the contents of the `webapp` directory, therefore I believe it should be the `DocumentRoot`. I cannot for the life of me get this working while keeping the rewrite for the PHP application/router functional.

My current VirtualHost configuration works, but the browser must be pointed to `site.dev/webapp`; navigating to `site.dev` shows a directory list.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site.dev

        ServerAdmin me@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site/

        LogLevel core:debug

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/site.error.log

    <Location />
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ /index.php [QSA,L]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Desired functionality is:

- `http://site.dev/` loads content from /webapp
- `http://site.dev/order/18` redirect to index.php passing `/order/18` from URI

Comment: If you want to serve something tho the browser it must be any kind of HTML, should this come from a file within /webapp (e.g. index.html or index.php) or is this handled by the /index.php file in /var/www/site/ ?

Comment: @Webdesigner static content for the frontend application is served from within /webapp e.g. index.html, js_lib.js etc.